# Redirect to another view in razor application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, httprequest

I have an asp.net mvc application in which i need to redirect to another page:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
            $('.Enregistrer').click(function () {
           window.location.href ="www.google.com";
                 });
    });
  </script>
```

i used `window.location.href` , `location.href`, `location.replace`  and `location` to try to redirect but it didn't work in two different browser (Chrome && IE)

What are the reasons? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the protocol (eg. `http://`) in the domain, otherwise it is assumed to be a local request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.Enregistrer').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // this may be required
            window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note I also added the `type` attribute to the `script` tag, and used `window.location.assign` as these are common best pratices.

Also, if `.Enregistrer` is an `a` element you may need to include `event.preventDefault` to stop the normal link behaviour.

Comment: Check the console for errors. Have you included `jquery.js` in your page?

Comment: How can i include `event.preventDefault`

Comment: @Lamloumi it's passed in to the click handler as a parameter. See my update for details

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Some browser didn't understand language

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('.Enregistrer').click(function () {
       window.location.href ="www.google.com";
             });
});
</script>
```